# Incrementing String by one with Perl

Tags: perl

why this perl code increment $v string by 1

```
 use strict;
    use warnings;

   my $v='AAAAAYAQUypALsDz';

    print ++$v
```

while the below is not:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my $v='AAAAAmGJoD1dlkkt';
    print ++$v
```

and i get Argument "AAAAAmGJoD1dlkkt" isn't numeric in preincrement (++)

any idea why this happens and how to increment such string by 1 using Perl?

Comment: "*The auto-increment operator has a little extra builtin magic to it. If you increment a variable that is numeric, or that has ever been used in a numeric context, you get a normal increment. If, however, the variable has been used in only string contexts since it was set, and has a value that is not the empty string and matches the pattern `/^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*\z/`, the increment is done as a string, preserving each character within its range, with carry"* The value in `$v` doesn't match the pattern that activates the "magic" string increment.

Comment: Besides, you have a mix of lowercase and uppercase letters in your string, so it doesn't make sense to use `++`; it couldn't possibly do what you want (whatever that is).

Answer (score 0):

As ikegami mentioned, perl does not interpret the second string as a number.
So you could do

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $v='AAAAAmGJoD1dlkkt';
my $v = scalar $v;
print ++$v;
```

Now if you want to add "1" to the end of the string, you should this

```
$v .= '1';
```